# Error in datagridview using ms acess(c#)

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-access-2007

the below mentioned code raises error "SYNTAX ERROR IN INSERT INTO STATEMENT"

here i took name and number field has text

no as autonumber(primary key)

```
con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:/ppd/db1.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=techsoft");

    da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from contacts", con);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds, "contacts");

    dt = ds.Tables[0];

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    OleDbConnection con;

     OleDbDataAdapter da;

     DataTable dt;

     OleDbCommand cm;  

    string insertQuery = @"insert into  contacts(names,number,no) Values (@names,@number,@no)";

    cm = new OleDbCommand(insertQuery, con);

    cm.Parameters.Add("@names", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "names");

    cm.Parameters.Add("@number", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "number");

     cm.Parameters.Add("@no", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "no");

    da.InsertCommand = cm;

    private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                da.Update(dt);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put text in a number-type field.  If "no" is autonumber, don't give it a value at all and it will auto-increment.  Just change the line that say:

```
string insertQuery = @"insert into  contacts(names,number,no) Values (@names,@number,@no)";
```

to

```
string insertQuery = @"insert into  contacts(names,number) Values (@names,@number)";
```

and remove the line that says

```
cm.Parameters.Add("@no", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "no");
```

Answer (score 0):

no is **Autonumber**, you **can not give autonumber** as parameter in your insert query.

Use below code :

```
con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:/ppd/db1.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=techsoft");

    da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from contacts", con);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds, "contacts");

    dt = ds.Tables[0];

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    OleDbConnection con;

     OleDbDataAdapter da;

     DataTable dt;

     OleDbCommand cm;  

    string insertQuery = @"insert into  contacts([names],[number]) Values (@names,@number)";

    cm = new OleDbCommand(insertQuery, con);

    cm.Parameters.Add("@names", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "names");

    cm.Parameters.Add("@number", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "number");


    da.InsertCommand = cm;
```

> Note : I have just removed no from
>   parameter list.